# android Preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

Actually I want to set different settings for each user using preference screen.Actually shared preference gives me same settings for each user.How to store each distinct settings for each user.Not use to preference screen so pls suggest how to do the same.

Comment: multiple users on one phone?

Comment: You can use multiple shared preferences file, one for each user. See here how it is done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6461844/1127492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the data using `sqlite`. then it will be easy to you

If you want to know more about sqlite then read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Means whenever user set the application settings,save settings using sqlite for each user and access according to user.

Comment: yeah..according to the userid you can get settings

Comment: when settings are set in pref. screen they are store in shared prefs. so cant I access from there..

Comment: yes you can. But let me tell confirm is the settings in phone for all users means-------is all users use `only one mobile`.

Comment: then use sqlite. because there may be limitation in the preferences. but sql can not store many number of records. so its better to use

Comment: so do I need preference screen for it..? to store in sqlite i can provide a menu for settings..